Orion 11j ERP suite - Automating the report extraction by a simple API call
I would like to know if anyone has downloaded the report from Orion11j ERP using a simple API call ? I know Orion 11j is accessible via SolarWinds API , but when I tried in python with the base URL of Orion report and with SWQL query, it didn't work because I don't have a clue about how the authentication side works. It requires an access token for sure I know. but how can I get that ? I just have a username and password to login and the download a report which I like to study. I'm curious to know if there are any other ways of programmatically extracting the data from Orion 11j.
any help would be much appreciated.
import requests
import json
import os
import csv

# Define your Orion server details
ORION_BASE_URL = "https://orion7.danubegroup.org:8485/11JLIVE/xhtml/login/homenew.xhtml#"
SWQL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Sales and GP Login Comp - BR Cost WHERE Date BETWEEN '2024-04-01' AND '2024-04-10'"

# Define your authentication details (replace with actual credentials)
ORION_USERNAME = "ORIONUSER"
ORION_PASSWORD = "********"

def execute_swql_query():
    try:
        # Authenticate and get an access token
        auth_url = f"{ORION_BASE_URL}/api/Account/Login"
        payload = {"Username": ORION_USERNAME, "Password": ORION_PASSWORD}
        response = requests.post(auth_url, json=payload)
        response_json = response.json()
        access_token = response_json.get("access_token")

        # Execute the SWQL query
        query_url = f"{ORION_BASE_URL}/api/SwisData/Query"
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
        payload = {"query": SWQL_QUERY}
        response = requests.post(query_url, json=payload, headers=headers)
        result_json = response.json()

        # Process the result and save to a CSV file
        if result_json:
            # Extract column names
            columns = list(result_json[0].keys())

            # Save data to CSV
            with open("sales_data.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=columns)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerows(result_json)

            print("SWQL query executed successfully. Data saved to sales_data.csv.")
        else:
            print("No data returned from the query.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(response.content)
        print(f"Error executing SWQL query: {str(e)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_swql_query()

